# Change cloned object without changing the original object

Tags: vba, object, set, clone, cloning

Is it possible to copy an object in VBA so that changes of the clone object do not affect the original object?

For example:

```
Dim clone_object As Variant
Set clone_object = some_object
some_object.Left = 0
clone_object.Left = 666
'I want it to show 0 instead of 666
Debug.print some_object.Left
```

Comment: That example doesn't help at all - it depends what object you're working with, but the premise is that you need to create a new instance of the object, this code is just assigning the original object to another variable - not 'cloning' it

Comment: Macro Man, it's an Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create methods like this in your class module (here it is `Config`) or do the same in the regular module if it is not a custom object :

```
Friend Sub SetConfig(SrcConfig As Config)
    Set Cfg = SrcConfig
End Sub

Public Function Copy() As Config
    Dim Result As Config
    Set Result = New Config
    Call Result.SetConfig(Cfg)
    Set Copy = Result
End Function
```

Comment: R3uK, that eventually solved my problem. Thank you much

Comment: Glad I could help! Enjoy SO! ;)